# The installation failed. Could not find a part of the path 'd:\local\temp\WFFM'

Tags: wffm, azure

The installation failed.
Could not find a part of the path 'd:\local\temp\WFFM'.

getting error while setting up wffm on cm server on azure.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error on azure, when the system is trying to use a machine local ressource. Instead the system should use azure "localresource" class, when using temp files.

The issue with Sitecore is, that generally the modules are not compatible with azure (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/880886) - at least not in 8.2.

WFFM IS working with Sitecore, but only in 8.1 - installation guide is here https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/81/setting_up_web_forms/installing/walkthrough_installing_wffm_on_sitecore_azure

LocalResource class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.localresource.aspx

Azure question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687903/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-on-windows-azure